# How to skip multiple directories when doing a find

Tags: linux, text, grep, directory, find

I've written a find function that searches for a string in each file in a given path, while skipping a list of directory names that I don't want searched.  I've placed this script in my .bashrc file to be called like so:

```
findTEXTinFILES /path/to/search 'text-to-find'
```

The find portion works great, and it colorizes the search text so that it visually stands out!, but I can't get it to skip the directories listed with -prune.  I've read all the posts here that I can find but none work for me.  I've tried multiple variations with no luck.  So I have a few questions:

- How do you skip multiple directories?
- How do you skip directories with just a partial name, such as those that begin with '--' or 'wp-'?
- Can you mix `-name` and `-path` criteria in the same script?
- Is there something else I've missed?

My server is CENTOS 6.9 virtuozzo with the bash shell.

```
function findTEXTinFILES {

find "$1" ! \( -name .bash_history -prune \
    -o ! -path tmp -prune \
    -o ! -path short -prune \
    -o ! -path "*/_not_used/*" -prune \
    -o ! -path backups -prune \
    -o ! -path temp_logs -prune \
    -o ! -name .cpan -prune \
    -o ! -name .cpobjcache -prune \
    -o ! -path files_to_compare -prune \
    -o ! -path logs -prune \
    -o ! -path mail -prune  \
    -o ! -path old -prune \
    -o ! -path '--*' -prune \
    -o ! -path 'wp-*' -prune \
    -o ! -path '*copy*' -prune \) \
    -o -name "*" \
    -exec grep $2 -I --color -Hn '$3' '{}' 2>/dev/null \;
}
```

Comment: Since posting this question, I found ack, a standalone Perl script that is super fast and produces excellent results.  I highly recommend it.  [link](https://beyondgrep.com)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A [`find` expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#find-Expressions) is composed primarily of *tests* and *actions* joined together with *operators*. It is evaluated in a standard short-circuiting manner -- meaning the evaluation is stopped as soon as the result is known, without the need to evaluate all parts (e.g. `true or anything` is evaluated to `true`).

Now note that [`-prune`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dprune-48) is an action that always returns `true`. It can act on the result of *any* test. Also note that the default operator is `-a` (*and*).

So, the simplest pruning example, to print all files except those under some path (e.g. `wp-*` in your example) looks like:

```
find . -path './wp-*' -prune -o -print
```

For files matching the path starting with `./wp-`, prune action is executed, meaning the result is `true`, and the right part of the OR operator can be ignored (i.e. file is not printed). Note here that `-path` matches relative path, in this case rooted at `.`, so we have to write `./wp-*` instead of `wp-*`.

To prune two paths, simply extend:

```
find . -path './wp-*' -prune -o -path ./logs -prune -o -print
```

Here: if first prune action is not executed (result `false`), then a chance is given to the second, if that doesn't prune neither (result `false`), then `-print` action is executed. In case any `-prune` gets evaluated, `-print` doesn't get a chance.

Applying this to your case:

```
find "$1" -name .bash_history -prune \
    -o -path "$1/tmp" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/short" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/*/_not_used/*" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/backups" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/temp_logs" -prune \
    -o -name "$1/.cpan" -prune \
    -o -name "$1/.cpobjcache" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/files_to_compare" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/logs" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/mail" -prune  \
    -o -path "$1/old" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/--*" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/wp-*" -prune \
    -o -path "$1/*copy*" -prune \
    -exec grep $2 -I --color -Hn '$3' '{}' 2>/dev/null \;
```

To avoid writing `$1`-dependent paths, you can `cd "$1"` and use f.e. `find . ... -path ./logs ...`.

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks!  +1 for the short circuiting explanation.  It looks like adding the current path (`$1`) makes it work.  I hadn't seen that explained before.  There are still a couple of situations where it doesn't work, though...

For testing, I created new directories and added files to be searched, but they're not being picked up by the script, though they are with a bare `find`.  Strange.  I also tried to skip files that have the word 'copy' in their name by adding `-o -name "$1/*copy*" -prune \ `, but they're still being returned in the search.

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome! (feel free to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your problem :-)). Regarding your `$1/*copy*` search -- you can't specify paths in `-name` test (only in `-path`). To prune paths containing word `copy`, use: `-name '*copy*' -prune`.